# ClassNotFoundException When Reading Parcel

Tags: android, exception

I am trying to restore my application from a Parcel (saved in a Bundle).

My Activity uses OpenGL so it creates this surface view and calls these functions when it is saving or restoring the app.

```
class MySurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    /* Lots of other stuff */
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
        Log.d("Wormhole", "Restoring instance state");
        mRenderer.onRestoreInstanceState(inState);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Log.d("Wormhole", "Saving instance state");
        mRenderer.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

in mRenderer

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
    mFlowManager = inState.getParcelable("flowmanager");
}

public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
    outState.putParcelable("flowmanager", mFlowManager);
}
```

in mFlowManager

```
public class FlowManager implements Touchable, Parcelable {
private enum State {
    SPLASH, MENU, GAME_SINGLE, GAME_MULTI
};

private Connection mConnection;
private ScoreDataSource mScoreDataSource;
private GameEngine mGameEngine;
private SplashScreen mSplash;
private MainMenu mMenu;
private State mState = State.SPLASH;
private long mTime;
private int mVersionID;

/* Other stuff */

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(mState.name());
    out.writeParcelable(mSplash, 0);
    out.writeParcelable(mMenu, 0);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<FlowManager> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FlowManager>() {
    public FlowManager createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new FlowManager(in);
    }

    public FlowManager[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FlowManager[size];
    }
};

private FlowManager(Parcel in) {
    mConnection = new Connection();

    mState = State.valueOf(in.readString());
    mSplash = in.readParcelable(null); // Exception occurs here
    mMenu = in.readParcelable(null);
}

}
```

The FlowManager class has instances of other classes that need to be saved. Those classes I made Parselable and it's when restoring them I get the error.

I've seen posts about this error but they all were for sending data between apps and having to use a different ClassLoader. This is all the same app. Do I need to set my ClassLoader because this is in a GLSurfaceView? How do I find the ClassLoader I need?

Comment: what is **mSplash**? can you paste entire `FlowManager` class

Comment: I added more to `FlowManager` the full class is very long with a lot of irrelevant code. mSplash is just another class I have `public class SplashScreen extends BasicScreen implements Parcelable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

update your `FlowManager(Parcel in)` as below:

```
private FlowManager(Parcel in) {
    mConnection = new Connection();

    mState = State.valueOf(in.readString());
    mSplash = in.readParcelable(SplashScreen.class.getClassLoader());
    mMenu = in.readParcelable(MainMenu.class.getClassLoader());
}
```